# Object Within an Object not passed to Child Component in Angular-2 Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following JSON Object within my Angular 2.4 Typescript code

```
variableJSON = 
{
  'fQuery': string,
  'fQueryRoot': string,
  'fQueryRootURL': string,
  'fName': string,
  'filterJSON': Object
}
```

The `filterJSON` Object is stored via an HTTP GET Response (based on Promise) for instance:

```
this.service.get(URL).then(
 // whatever is returned from promise is stored in the above JSON
res => this.variableJSON['filterJSON'] = res);
```

I am pushing the the above mentioned `variableJSON` within an Array and passing it to my child component as follows:

```
<child-comp *ngFor="let eachFilter of arrayPassingToChild" [filterProperties]="eachFilter">
<!-- assuming eachFilter is the exact variableJSON mentioned Above passed to child -->
</child-comp>
```

When I do a Console Log on the Parent Component the Object pushed to the Array shows the `filterJSON` Object completely. On the contrary when I do the Console log on `filterProperties` which is an `@Input()` in the child component:

I get all the strings viz. `fQuery` .. etc. but `filterJSON` Object is completely Empty.

What is the possible reason for this?

### Inference

I presume that the Array created gets passed earlier than the Promise returned by HTTP GET and perhaps maybe the `filterJSON` is empty.

#### Info

The child component are just CSS Boxes which get displayed with the Data within the above mentioned JSON. In general context, when a just clicks a particular place the CSS boxes appear.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding you, but shouldn't you be passing `[filterProperties]="eachFilter.filterJSON"` to extract just the filterJSON? What exactly is in your `arrayPassingToChild`?

Comment: the Array consists of the complete JSON structure above. In the child component i wish to do something like `this.variable['filterJSON']` should give me the Object

Comment: Gotcha, can you post your component code?

Comment: `ngFor` and `@Input()` do not modify inner properties of array elements. Therefore you're looking in the wrong spots for your bug.

Comment: Let me add a complete summary to make things clear.

Comment: @joshrathke as much as I wish it is more than 300 lines long. It consists of Diagram created using GoJS and other complexities

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are passing in the real data and not just the interface of the data you will get it.

Here is a plunker to go off of.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4TRbOejaUmhDmI170aPI?p=preview

App Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>App Started</div>
    <child-component [data]="point" *ngFor="let point of data"></child-component>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [{
      point : 0
    },{
      point : 1
    },{
      point : 2
    }]
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
   <div>Got Data Point {{data.point}}</div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
   @Input() data;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Output

```
App Started
Got Data Point 0
Got Data Point 1
Got Data Point 2
```

Comment: I think this makes sense. However are they any provisions when the data is relying on Promise from a service?

Comment: Not really, the point of data flow is so we don't need to worry about the data delay. It could be an issue if you are not getting the data at all. Take a look at what happens if the data is delayed. If you are not getting the data at all I would looking at your service to find out what's wrong.
http://plnkr.co/edit/qv96dXucomDvrJuYMk3r?p=preview

Comment: Yes. I added an `TimeOut` for a second to wait till the promise is fulfilled and then pushed the Object to the Array. This works.

Comment: I would place a trigger/then callback to the promise to fill the array only after it is completed.

Comment: That sounds like the right option. Should I place a timeout within the `this.service.get()` call and once the call is complete then push the Object into the array ?

Comment: No, you can't guarantee the amount of time it needs to process. I would say use a function that is triggered after the service has completed it's process. I have gone done the path of using timeouts for these kind of things and it is a bad idea.

Comment: Use something like this.service.get().then(()=>{/*Fill the array*/}); If you are not passing the promise directly you should be, it helps a lot.